# convert from System.String to PCTSTR

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I'm having to convert from System.String (C#) into a PCTSTR which would be typed as _nullterminated const char*

So far I can't find anything that can tell me exactly how to do this.

Plenty of examples to convert from System::String (C++/CLI), but I can't find anything on System.String (C#)

I'm working in Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: If you explicitly want a C# answer rather than a C++/CLI answer, why did you tag this `c++-cli`?

Comment: Aren't System.String and System::String the same thing?

Comment: @peachykeen I don't know how to make a native C++ char* to marshal into, within the C# language. It's easy in C++/CLI, because C++/CLI supports native C++ datatypes.

Comment: I believe your first step would be to go to a `char[]` in C#. That's significantly closer; all you need to worry about is charset.

Comment: Why do you need the PCSTR? Do you need to PInvoke some function that takes it as an argument?

Comment: @peachykeen : When `TCHAR` is `char`, `PCTSTR` would be `sbyte[]` in C# (but `byte[]` suffices); when `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, `PCTSTR` would be `char[]` in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `PCTSTR` is a typedef for `const char*`, use [Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx).

When `PCTSTR` is a typedef for `const wchar_t*`, use [Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobaluni.aspx).

In both cases, call [Marshal.FreeHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx) to free the memory when you're done with it; despite your using C#, the memory allocation in question is unmanaged, so consequently is not eligible for garbage collection and **will** leak if you don't clean it up properly.

Comment: I'll need to use Ansi either way, because the destination will expect ASCII.

Comment: @Xaade : Okay, fair enough. :-] But for your edification, if it's always ASCII that's expected, then that's a `PCSTR`, not `PCTSTR` -- by definition the latter changes between `PCSTR` and `PCWSTR` according to whether or not `UNICODE` is defined.

Answer (score 4):

You should use Marshal static class

```
var str = "Hello world" 
var marshalledStr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(str).ToPointer()
```

See complete reference on marshalling http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use it in a PInvoke call, you can just declare the parameter as `string`, and use `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)`:

```
[DllImport("somelib.dll")]
static extern void function([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string s);
```

Comment: That would be nice if the people that invented this native C++ DLL used arguments to their methods instead of godawful structs.

Comment: @Xaade : The same can work for structs -- no manual marshaling necessary. It would help if your question showed what you _actually_ need to pass in, because my answer is probably the worst approach possible given your actual scenario.