# Using SymSrvStoreFileW from DBGHELP

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke

I am trying to invoke `SymSrvStoreFileW` from DBGHELP.DLL (after a previous failed attempt at getting `SymSrvGetFileIndexInfoW` to work). The important functions are defined as follows in MSDN:

```
BOOL WINAPI SymInitialize(
  _In_      HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_opt_  PCTSTR UserSearchPath, // null is documented as fine
  _In_      BOOL fInvadeProcess // false
);

PCTSTR WINAPI SymSrvStoreFile(
  _In_      HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_opt_  PCTSTR SrvPath, // e.g. "srv*C:\symbols"
  _In_      PCTSTR File, // e.g. "C:\myapp.pdb"
  _In_      DWORD Flags // I am using SYMSTOREOPT_RETURNINDEX (0x04)
);

BOOL WINAPI SymCleanup(
  _In_  HANDLE hProcess
);
```

**hProcess** is a little strange, from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681351.aspx) I gather that it really doesn't matter what you pass into it, so long as you remain consistent. I have used both the current process ID and a 'any old value' ID. Neither worked.

I made the following `externs`:

```
[DllImport("dbghelp.dll", EntryPoint = "SymInitializeW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SymInitialize(
    IntPtr process,
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    string searchPath, 
    bool invadeProcess);

[DllImport("dbghelp.dll", EntryPoint = "SymCleanup", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SymCleanup(IntPtr process);

[DllImport("dbghelp.dll", EntryPoint = "SymSrvStoreFileW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
public static extern string SymSrvStoreFile(
    IntPtr process,
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    string srvPath,
    [param: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    string file,
    SymStoreOpt options);

enum SymStoreOpt : uint
{
    None = 0x00,
    Compress = 0x01,
    Overwrite = 0x02,
    Pointer = 0x08,
    ReturnIndex = 0x04,
    PassIfExists = 0x40,
}
```

And attempted a call:

```
var processId = IntPtr.Zero;
try
{
    // This succeeds.
    processId = new IntPtr(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
    if (!NativeMethods.SymInitialize(processId, null, false))
    {
        processId = IntPtr.Zero;
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    // This fails.
    var storageLocation = NativeMethods.SymSrvStoreFile(processId, "srv*C:\\vssym", "C:\\test\\mscorlib.pdb", SymStoreOpt.ReturnIndex);
    if (storageLocation == null)
    {
        // Errors under various circumstances.
        // - The operation completed successfully (but storageLocation is still null)
        // - The specified module could not be found
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
}
finally
{
    if (processId != IntPtr.Zero)
        NativeMethods.SymCleanup(processId);
}
```

Are there any mistakes with my `extern` declarations? Alternatively, anyone know how to get the symbol storage location for a PDB/PE (and not only a .Net one)? I have also tried the other `SymStoreOpt` flags and got nowhere.

At some point (I can't remember what I did) the file appeared in the symbol storage location (even though `ReturnIndex` was used), but at that point my process would crash (one of those where the debugger doesn't even catch it), running it again would result in "the operation succeeded" with no return value.

**EDIT:** [I tried this in C++](https://gist.github.com/ce87bd824654e84eb375) and still get the same behavior - obviously I don't want to go that route because P/Invoke has the advantage of architecture neutrality.

Comment: Is the `_processId` in your `SymSrvStoreFile` a typo?

Comment: Its actually occurring, in C++ too. https://gist.github.com/ce87bd824654e84eb375 - any ideas?

Comment: @Richard yes, thanks. I actually pulled it out of the wrapper class to make things simpler - the effect is still the same though.

Comment: OK, my only other thought is the marshalling of the `PCTSTR` strings. I think you'll need to use `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni` for these: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7033489/124386

Comment: Although a later answer suggests that `UnmanagedType.LPTStr` should be OK: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7034011/124386

Comment: @Richard yep, I did actually try that - it was as effective as the current code is. It is interesting that C++ is doing the same thing: meaning I am fumbling with the call.